# Why is $f(x) = |x|$ not surjective?

Tags: functions

Can anyone explain to me why the function
$$
f(x)=|x|
$$
is not surjective (onto)?

I think it should be, but my teacher told me it's not.

Comment: What value of $x$ will you put into $f(x)$ in order to get $-1$?

Comment: What domain and range are you using for this function? I ask because if you are using domain $(-\infty,+\infty)$ and range $[0,\infty)$ then it **is** surjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f \colon X \to Y$ is said to be onto if for each $y \in Y$, there exists $x \in X$ such that $f(x)=y$.

You have not specified the domain and codomain of the your function.

In fact, it is onto when you consider it as a function from $\mathbb R$ to $[0,\infty)$.

However, it is not onto when considered as a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ as there does not exist a pre-image for any $x<0$.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your definition of $f$. Consider $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ where $x \mapsto |x|$, this is certainly not surjective because every negative value $(-\infty, 0)$ is not mapped to by $f$.

Whereas one could define $f : \mathbb R \to [0, \infty)$, which would be surjective, but not injective.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Assume $f $ is considered as function defined from $\mathbb R $ to $\mathbb R $.

$$\forall x\in\mathbb R \;\; f (x)=|x|\ge 0$$

$$\implies f (\mathbb R)\subset [0,+\infty)$$
$$\implies f (\mathbb R)\ne \mathbb R $$

$\implies \; f $ is not surjective.

Comment: How do you know? The OP did not tell us what the codomain of the function is.